# Android Input Dialog Box's Onclick doesn't work

Tags: java, android, user-interface

so I am new to programming in Android so I apologize if this is a beginner mistake, but I was programming my button to add a user to an array list with the name given in the dialog box.  When I run it, everything works except when it executes users.add(new User(name)); (It returns a null pointerI'm unsure as to why this is the case.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code.

```
addPersonButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final EditText input = new EditText(mainActivity);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity)
            .setTitle("New User")
            .setMessage("What is the new user's name?")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    final String name = input.getText().toString();
                    users.add(new User(name));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: where hv u initialized users?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is with `input` in `onClick` method, and because `input` in your `dialog layout` not in `main layout`, so you must use following code:

```
    final String name = dialog.input.getText().toString();
    users.add(new User(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

create edittext in xml and use `findViewById(R.id.edittext);`

or in java

```
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
```

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572758/2675669)